# Unwanted text everytime i create an object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was testing a program to create cars with their respective make, model and horsepower. The program has a function to delete the objects. The problem is that every time I create an object the print of that function is executed without me having called the **del** function. I am using Python 3.10.1.

```
class Car:

    amount_cars = 0

    def __init__(self, manufacturer, model, HP):
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer
        self.model = model
        self.HP = HP
        Car.amount_cars += 1

        
    def __del__(self):
        print("Object deleted!")
        Car.amount_cars -= 1

    def print_info(self):
        print("Manufacturer: {}, Model: {}, HP: {}".format(self.manufacturer,self.model,self.HP))        

    def print_car_amount(self):
        print("Amount: {}".format(Car.amount_cars))



myCar1 = Car("Ford","Gol","1800")
myCar2 = Car("Renault","12","19000")
myCar3 = Car("Tesla","AEX-1","8000")
myCar4 = Car("Chevrolet","Onix","6700")


del myCar3
myCar1.print_car_amount()
```

Comment: They are deleted when the program ends.

Comment: The garbage collector automatically deletes objects when they're no longer accessible.

Comment: is there a way to prevent that from happening? (I mean not showing that the objects were deleted)

Comment: Don't use the `__del__` method for this. Define your own method. `del` is for deleting variables, not objects.

Comment: You should also split this into two classes. One class for `Car` and another class for `CarCollection`.

Comment: the `__del__` special method is for deleting/destroy the object, and your overwrite doesn't do that in any way shape or form, most of the time you don't need to overwrite that method and should be done only if you know if you know what you're doing